# How to create Listview items + Button in each row?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and this task is really need for my school project. Please kindly help me.

I've string array List - (retrieved from csv)

```
  list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("111,222,333,444,555,666".split(",")));
  myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.cell,list));
```

The result is showing only line by line text of arrayList. I want to add button to each generated line by line to delete clicked row.

Please how can I do this. Thank you for understanding my problem.

Comment: You need to create custom `ListView`!!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Create your own `Adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` in `R.layout.cell` add a button next to the `TextView`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create a custom layout xml which having a single item then you will add your button to this layout along with any other items.

CustomLayout.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" /> 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call" /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now after creating custom item layout you need listview which holds all items.

MainActivity.xml

```
.
.
<ListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
.
.
```

Now in java file just set adapter with our custom layout xml

```
.
.
list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("111,222,333,444,555,666".split(",")));
listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(list, context) );
.
.
```

Custom adapter Class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter { 
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private Context context; 

public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) { 
    this.list = list; 
    this.context = context; 
} 

@Override
public int getCount() { 
    return list.size(); 
} 

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) { 
    return list.get(pos); 
} 

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) { 
    return list.get(pos).getId();
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
} 

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.CustomLayout, null);
    } 

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView tvContact= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvContact); 
    tvContact.setText(list.get(position)); 

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button callbtn= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    callbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //do something

        }
    });
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //do something
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            .
        }
    });

    return view; 
} 
}
```

Comment: (https://s13.postimg.org/rlqjuukhz/Capture.png) Very near to be solved my problem but I can't fix this. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: write " return pos; " over there

Comment: Really Thank you for great working answer code . :) . You save my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have need **ListviewActivity** for listing your data

**SchoolAdapter** which is custom adapter to inflate each individual row

**activity_listview** which is layout for ListviewActivity

**view_listview_row** which is required for each individual row

Now create all file as below

For **ListviewActivity**,

```
public class ListviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListview;
private ArrayList<String> mArrData;
private SchoolAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

    mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSchool);

    // Set some data to array list
    mArrData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("111,222,333,444,555,666".split(",")));

    // Initialize adapter and set adapter to list view
    mAdapter = new SchoolAdapter(ListviewActivity.this, mArrData);
    mListview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

For **SchoolAdapter**,

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mArrSchoolData;

public SchoolAdapter(Context context, ArrayList arrSchoolData) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
    mArrSchoolData = arrSchoolData;
}

public int getCount() {
    // return the number of records
    return mArrSchoolData.size();
}

// getView method is called for each item of ListView
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // inflate the layout for each item of listView
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_listview_row, parent, false);


    // get the reference of textView and button
    TextView txtSchoolTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSchoolTitle);
    Button btnAction = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

    // Set the title and button name
    txtSchoolTitle.setText(mArrSchoolData.get(position));
    btnAction.setText("Action " + position);

    // Click listener of button
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Logic goes here
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}}
```

For **activity_listview**,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D1FFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listSchool"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#0000CC"
    android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"></ListView>
```

For **view_listview_row**,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="7.5dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="7.5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSchoolTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

At last but not least, do not forgot to add your activity in **manifest.xml**

Comment: Thank you for answering. You too a great answer. Really thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom list view in another file with the only content of each item in the list.

Then create a Custom `Adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` and bind it.

Please refer to this website for example.

https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/

OR

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/